# Empty blank space at bottom of page?

Tags: html, css, layout

In my current simple project, [Copybin](http://dflog.net/copybin2/), there is some space at the bottom of the page that I cannot seem to be able to remove it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the following CSS on your page:

```
body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background-color:#eef8ff;
    min-width:950px;
    min-height:975px;
}
```

Remove your min-height:975px;. This will allow your page to expand to whatever height it requires. I measured your page up and its exactly 975 pixels high.

Answer (score 1):

try wrapping everything in a div tag and then seeting its height to the height of your web template and put overflow hidden.

```
<body>
<div style="height:800px; overflow:hidden;">
    <!-- rest of your code -->
</div>
</body>
```